# I can't put anything on my desktop and i can't change the wallpaper. Lubuntu 16.04

Tags: lubuntu, desktop-background, lxde, pcmanfm

I can't change my wallpaper and I can't put any files on my desktop. Also my right-click menu changed from the normal one to the one in the image.

[image]

Comment: Click log out in the right-click menu and then, when you log in again, make sure you select the Lubuntu desktop session and not the Openbox session. If this works for you, post what you did as an answer.

Comment: I logged out and now the Lubuntu DE has disappeared from my login screen.

Comment: Can you please make sure that `lubuntu-desktop` is installed (run `sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get upgrade -f lubuntu-desktop` and verify that it succeeds)?

Answer (score 2):

Try typing this in a terminal:

```
pcmanfm --desktop-pref
```

You can change the desktop wallpaper from this window.

And uncheck the box "Show menus provided by window managers when desktop is clicked" found under the "Advanced" tab.

Then you should be able to right click on the desktop and get the menu to bring up the preferences window that allows you to change the wallpaper anytime.