# Lubuntu background has disapered unable to fix it

Tags: lubuntu, desktop-background, autostart

I moved my file manager application 'pcmanfm-qt' from my accessories folder over onto the desktop then over to the autostart folder /home/myusername/.config/autostart, for some reason this made my wallpaper disappear and when I tried to change it back through Desktop preferences the option to do so became unavailable screen shot below.

https://imgur.com/jO9EaMV

I believe moving my file manager around so many times messed up my background because when I followed some instructions I found here.

[I can't put anything on my desktop and i can't change the wallpaper. Lubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1026702/i-cant-put-anything-on-my-desktop-and-i-cant-change-the-wallpaper-lubuntu-16)

pcmanfm --dekstop-pref returned this.

https://imgur.com/pe0Kdey

not sure what to do now though  checked my wallpapers folder and everything is still there reset my laptop as well, I'm on a 2009 MBP currently running Lubuntu 22.04.2 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish) LXQT version 0.17.0.

Edit: almost forgot I followed these instructions as well.

[Lubuntu - Desktop Preferences error ¨Desktop Manager Not Active¨](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1108466/lubuntu-desktop-preferences-error-%C2%A8desktop-manager-not-active%C2%A8)

pcmanfm --desktop doesn't do anything I have to do ctrl+c after executing it because nothing happens.

Edit 2: menu://applications/Accessories/pcmanfm-qt.desktop is the app I moved. [image]

Edit 3: I ran sudo pcmanfm-qt --desktop-pref myusername thinking that I needed root permission to change my wallpaper back to normal but this didn't make the  the 'wallpaper image file' option available

Edit 4: checked the man page and tried pcmanfm-qt --set-wallpaper lubuntu-default-wallpaper.png still blank didn't work.

Comment: It may help if you're very specific, ie. I'm unsure what you meant by "*moved my file manager application*" as `pcmanfm-qt` is the main program that controls what we see as the LXQt desktop (*including displaying the wallpaper*) so changes to it can impact desktop operation (ie. it is more than just the file-manager).  You also mention `pcmanfm` which is a different app (older GTK2 version used by LXDE and not used since Lubuntu 18.04 being replaced by the Qt5 port by same author ([PCMan](https://github.com/PCMan)) named `pcmanfm-qt`).

Comment: strange I have pcmanfm-qt and pcmanfm installed for some reason I've been messing around in the terminal a lot lately so it's possible I downloaded the other by mistake, any way I went to menu://applications/Accessories and moved the 'pcmanfm-qt.desktop' app that was inside to my desktop ill take a screen shot for you.

Comment: @guiverc ok I added the photo

Comment: I'm betting you've added it, as a quick look here (https://cdimage.ubuntu.com/lubuntu/jammy/daily-live/current/jammy-desktop-amd64.manifest which is what is included on the *daily* of *jammy* (22.04) ISO shows only `pcmanfm-qt) as including *deprecated* `pcmanfm` would force a load of other *deprecated* libs/toolkits to be used & be rather wasteful on resources (ie. **not light**)..  Please add additional details to your question & not reply via comments.

Comment: Also please note:  Lubuntu up to 18.04 used the LXDE desktop; thus when reading *how to* or posts about LXDE, you need to *convert* them into the equivalent for a LXQt desktop (ie. release of 18.10 or later).. the link you provided referencing `pcmanfm` would have required you to *convert* that to be `pcmanfm-qt` to work.. likewise additional packages may also need changing so if instructions are for 18.04 or earlier take note as you may need to *alter* what you read to have it work (*and not complicate*) your newer LXQt system.

Comment: Yup pcmanfm has been uninstalled I still have the same problem though thank you for the tip.

Comment: Sorry I'm busy on other tasks and thus can't look at this currently (*quick comments I can make as I scan between starting my next task, but to look at this will require thought (understanding what you did) & thus like PDF.manual & other tasks in my 'todo queue'*).   Others may respond in mean time...

Comment: FYI: I don't have anything to offer [yet]... On a *fresh* QA install (*alas lunar/23.04*) I believe I worked out what you did.. however it didn't have the effect you mention for me at all... That could mean I did something different OR a consequence of my later LXQt (1.2)  (*note: also this was a clean/unused install, with no LXDE or other changes that may have meant your effects differed*).... I used *lunar* (23.04) as it was on the QA test machine I grabbed.

Comment: Hey again @guiverc I managed to fix my problem though I'm still not 100% certain how the the error occurred (not able to recreate it) ill be adding the solution soon spoke to another person recently that lost their background as well at one point I plan on speaking to him again soon and adding more details to this post. Thanks for staying in touch ill be on the lubuntu forum soon take care :D

Comment: FYI:   I've experienced a *black* screen many times too, one easy way to create it is by logging in using a Openbox session (its `pcmanfm-qt` that puts the wallpaper up on the desktop; openbox session doesn't start LXQt/pcmanfm-qt naturally; other causes too whilst using LXQt, but I didn't found a connection or anything helpful for you either; thus why no reply). Thanks for update - appreciated !